# Returning the word with multiple instances of a character using regex

Tags: python, regex

I tried finding a solution by using only **re.compile** and **findall** but I can't seem to get it. I am looking to return the string which has multiple instances of any character inside (e.g macdonalds kfc burgerking) and the result should be

`[(macdonalds, ad),(burgerking,rg)]`

I tried the code

`` p = re.compile(r`\w+(.)\1{1,}\w+`) ``

`p.findall('macdonalds kfc burgerking')`

but it could only search for instances that concur simultaneously. (e.g Baaaabaaa sheep)

Answer (score 0):

With Python `re`, you can use

```py
import re
rx = re.compile(r'\w*?(\w)\w*\1\w*')
rx_extract_dupe = re.compile(r'(.)(?=.*\1)')
text = 'macdonalds kfc burgerking'
matches = rx.finditer(text)
print( [(x.group(), "".join(rx_extract_dupe.findall(x.group()))) for x in matches] )
# => [('macdonalds', 'ad'), ('burgerking', 'rg')]
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/bybbUh). With `\w*?(\w)\w*\1\w*` regex, you extract all words with at least one char repetition, and then `(.)(?=.*\1)` with `.findall()` applied to the match gets the list of duplicated chars.

If you install the PyPi regex library you can use

```py
import regex
rx = regex.compile(r'(?:\w*?(\w)(?=\w*\1))+\w*')
text = 'macdonalds kfc burgerking'
print( [(x.group(), "".join(x.captures(1)) ) for x in rx.finditer(text)] )
# => [('macdonalds', 'ad'), ('burgerking', 'rg')]
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEETv/Yqll@yqBMSbUPoh1kNN07rWJmGb0vj1MeJpHgNvJnzi07tLzrwELxHETjZVkqD5ozZ@Cfy2KArba7cfWux2wrYp2J2JjiUVVdGmWBS19Gbwrn8PK8yjgccmk5WZ3aSqIOwiwg2TnsRvAekEda1fnl2pTB/iJnbFsgkEoxdIwA4k6ZHdwNEK/k7oDpTzFw).

*Details*:

- `(?:\w*?(\w)(?=\w*\1))+` - one or more sequences of

  - `\w*?`  - zero or more word chars, as few as possible
  - `(\w)` - Group 1: any single word char
  - `(?=\w*\1)` - that is followed with zero or more word chars and then the same word char as captured in Group 1
- `\w*` - any zero or more word chars.

The `x.group()`  contains a match value and `x.captures(1)` contains all occurrences of the repeated characters in a word.

Comment: What if you do not have regex library and only to use compile? is it still possible?

Comment: @PythonLearner You will still need to add some code. I added the `re` code, too.

Comment: the code seems to only group the instances. without using the group command, is it possible to group the word with the instances in two different group?

Comment: @PythonLearner What I shared is what you can use to get your expected output. These two solutions showcase what you can do with regex.